# Trigger script to run once on logon of specific new user

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, login

I have a PowerShell script that replaces data to a user's profile (Desktop, My Docs, ...). I would like to have this script run immediately once the new user logs onto their machine. I cannot do it before the user logs on because their profile is not built yet.

Also, this has to work on XP and w7.

Comment: why don't you use windows task scheduler?

Comment: from reading http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569, there does not seem to be a way to schedule a task after a specific user logs on